# How to customize customized properties for WebSphere using wsadmin with values in non-English characters

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin, non-english

I am trying to create jython script that will load list of properties and will customize the server-> JVM -> custom properties.

I managed to create a script using the AdminConfig tasks, the problem is that some of the values contains non-English characters (Hebrew to be more precise), and the Jython does not managed to read them correctly

Answer (score 0):

The solution was combined-
The loading of the properties files was done with InputStreamReader that used UTF8 character set-

```
inStream = javaio.FileInputStream(propsFil)
instreader = javaio.InputStreamReader(inStream, "UTF8")
propFil = util.Properties()
propFil.load(instreader)
```

After that I needed to use the AdminTask instead of AdminConfig-

```
AdminTask.setJVMSystemProperties('[-serverName '+ server + ' -nodeName '+ node+ ' -propertyName '+ config_property +' -propertyValue ' + config_value + ' ]')
```